# Appending new key value pairs into the existing shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Please can any one tell me how to append new key value pairs into the existing shared preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to add key value Pair to the Shared Preference :

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.putInt("key1", 1);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: But i want to add the values from the different activity to the already existing preference.

Comment: This should serve the purpose as long as you use the same identifier i.e. MY_PREFS_NAME here. Make sure that you put in the same identifier in every activity. Perhaps you could make a Utility class and define a static String constant for the identifier and use it in all of your activities.

Comment: Use MY_PREFS_NAME in another activity when you want to add new key-pair value.